# How to use multiple interfaces through WCF in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a number of WCF services that all have a certain method `ServicePing` that returns some information about the service.  I want to be able to abstract this method into an interface so that I can use it in the client.

I went to the first service and moved the `ServicePing` method into an `IPingable` interface.  I then made the existing interface inherit from `IPingable`.  When I update the service and regenerate the proxy, I can see the method, but the proxy class itself does not implement `IPingable`, although that is the location of the calls.

Then I went back to the service and instead of making the interface inherit `IPingable`, I made the service itself implement both interfaces.  Now I can't even see the method in the generated class.

If there's not a way to get both interfaces through to the client, then I was considering adding on to the generated `Partial Class`.  Something like

```
Partial Public Class GeneratedClass
  Implements IGeneratedClassContract

  Public Function ServicePing() As Boolean Implements IGeneratedClassContract.ServicePing
    'Definition
```

Adding this:

```
Partial Public Class GeneratedClass
  Implements IPingable

  Public Function ServicePing() As Boolean Implements IPingable.ServicePing
    `Call IGeneratedClassContract.ServicePing
```

Is there a way to update the existing call to also implement the other (exactly the same) method?  Is this the best way to get a single method to implement two interfaces when you can't update the definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can see your method ServicePing() from ServiceReference.PingableClient provided IPingable is marked as [ServiceContract] and ServicePing() method is marked as [OperationContract].

Happy coding...